# Flickity: is-selected class cannot view image

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flickity

Yesterday I have a user-unfriendliness carousel. Then I search for other flexible and responsive carousel solution, then thankfully I got this **Flickity's carousels** a fun to flick by  David DeSandro. Now, **I got a problem in adding image. I cannot see any picture**. Original file located here http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/gbjzre. My codes are the following below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Flickity</title>
    <!--Flickity-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="gallery js-flickity" data-flickity='{ "autoPlay": true }'>
        <div class="gallery-cell"> <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/orange-tree.jpg" alt="orange tree" /></div>
        <div class="gallery-cell"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg" alt="submerged" /></div>
        <div class="gallery-cell"> <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/one-world-trade.jpg" alt="One World Trade" /></div>
        <div class="gallery-cell"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/drizzle.jpg" alt="drizzle" /></div>
        <div class="gallery-cell"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/cat-nose.jpg" alt="cat nose" /></div>
        <div class="gallery-cell"> <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/contrail.jpg" alt="contrail" /></div>
        <div class="gallery-cell"> <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/golden-hour.jpg" alt="golden hour" /></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
<style type="text/css">
/* external css: flickity.css */

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.gallery-cell {
    width: 28%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #8C8;
    counter-increment: gallery-cell;
}

.gallery-cell.is-selected {
    background: #ED2;
}

/* cell number */

.gallery-cell:before {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    content: counter(gallery-cell);
    line-height: 200px;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: white;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
// external js: flickity.pkgd.js
</script>
```

Comment: You either remove the unnecessary `<div>` with class `.gallery-cell` like [this](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/GgQREP), or set `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;` to your `.gallery-cell img`.

Comment: Thanks, It works fine. @Ricky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the following solution @Ricky here the following solution you've given to me. 
The 1st way. I just remove the `<div class="gallery-cell">` instead I just add the `class="gallery-cell"` inside `img` element.

```
<img class="gallery-cell" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/contrail.jpg" alt="contrail" />
```

The 2nd solution, I just add the codes inside my `.gallery-cell:before`

```
.gallery-cell:before {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
   /* content: counter(gallery-cell);*/
    line-height: 200px;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: white;

    /*@Ricky  2nd Solution*/
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
}
```